# Standard practice to implement a levelling system where each level unlocks something new

Tags: java

Here's a quick scenario. Imagine I have a mine which I can upgrade from level 1 to 3.

Level 1 mine: Can mine bronze. 100hp.

Level 2 mine: Can mine silver. 200hp.

Level 3 mine: Can mine gold. 300hp.

I want to be able to upgrade the mines from level 1 to level 2 to level 3. Currently, I can just do this all in one class and have an upgradeLevel() method update the level and hp attribute. Then my mineBronze(), mineSilver() and mineGold() methods could just check the level attribute and perform the action if we clear the level requirement. However, this doesn't seem very java-like to just have one class which does all the updating itself. I was wondering how do people generally implement upgrading/levelling systems in java?

I thought about something basic like the following UML diagram:
*Mine* <-- Level1Mine <-- Level2Mine <-- Level3Mine.

In order to upgrade, I would have to downcast. Here's a rough example of an implementation.

```
public abstract class Mine() {
    private String location; // Doesn't really matter, just some location. Does not change with upgrades.
    
    public Mine(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public boolean mineBronze() {
       return false;
    }

    public boolean mineSilver() {
       return false;
    }

    public boolean mineGold() {
       return false;
    }

    public abstract int getHp();
}

public class Level1Mine extends Mine {
    
    public Level1Mine(String location) {
        super(location);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean mineBronze() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public int getHp() {
       return 100;
    }

    // How to upgrade from level 1 to level 2? Do I need an upgrade method?
}
```

Then Level2Mines do the same thing but override the mineSilver method. Level3Mines override the mineGold method, etc. The problem with this is, the only way to upgrade seems to be downcasting from Level1Mine to Level2Mine and everywhere I google suggests that this is bad practice.

I think someone mentioned using a decorator pattern somewhere so I tried that as well and I won't type out the entire decorator implementation here because it would be too long but I'll type out what the usage would look like inside main:

```
Level1Mine mine1 = new Level1Mine();
Level2Mine mine2 = new Level2Mine(mine1);
Level3Mine mine3 = new Level3Mine(mine2);
```

where upgrading would involve wrapping the previous level with a decorator which provides additional functionality. But again, this upgrading seems to be a pain.

Basically I'm not sure how what is the standard practice to implement something like this levelling/upgrading system in java. It seems that my original way of having everything in a single class which updates itself was the best (even though it feels like bad practice). Could someone show me how to implement this and especially how to upgrade from one level to another? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use your simple example to illustrate the use of an interface and multiple concrete class implementations of the interface.

> Level 1 mine: Can mine bronze. 100hp.
>
> Level 2 mine: Can mine silver. 200hp.
>
> Level 3 mine: Can mine gold. 300hp.

If mining and hit points were the only things that leveling up did, this approach would be overengineered.  The power of using an interface and concrete classes comes when there are multiple changes with levels.

First, we create a `Player` class.  This is a plain Java class with getters and setters.

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    
    private int level;
    private int maximumHitPoints;
    private int miningLevel;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    public int getMaximumHitPoints() {
        return maximumHitPoints;
    }
    public void setMaximumHitPoints(int maximumHitPoints) {
        this.maximumHitPoints = maximumHitPoints;
    }
    public int getMiningLevel() {
        return miningLevel;
    }
    public void setMiningLevel(int miningLevel) {
        this.miningLevel = miningLevel;
    }
}
```

This class would contain the values for the level, the mining level, and the maximum hit points.

Now, you could update this class with a list of `if-else` statements, or a `switch` statement.  That gets messy pretty quickly when you have 30 levels and 10 different level values.

So, the first thing you do is create a level interface.  Let's call it `Level`.

```
public interface Level {
    public boolean isLevel(int level);
    public Player updateLevel(Player player);
}
```

Looks pretty simple.  Now, let's see one concrete class implementation of this interface.

```
public class Level1 implements Level {

    @Override
    public boolean isLevel(int level) {
        return (level == 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Player updateLevel(Player player) {
        player.setLevel(1);
        player.setMiningLevel(1);
        player.setMaximumHitPoints(100);
        return player;
    }
    
}
```

Yes, you have to create a concrete class implementation for each level.

Finally, you build a `List` of concrete implementations.  The `createLevels` method would have one line for each level.  Then, when you want to update the player statistics, you just iterate through the `List` like this.

```
Public class Levels {
    
    private List<Level> levels;
    
    public Levels() {
        this.levels = new ArrayList<>();
        createLevels();
    }
    
    private void createLevels() {
        this.levels.add(new Level1());
    }
    
    public void updatePlayer(Player player, int levelNum) {
        for (Level level : levels) {
            if (level.isLevel(levelNum)) {
                level.updateLevel(player);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look/search how a finite state machine is implemented in Java, this will be your answer. I would've no problems when using a single class for all this. Overcomplicating things isn't always good ;-)